# Angular 2 \ 4 URL rewrite affecting data api in iis server

Tags: angular, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

i have an angular app, which has 3 pages:

```
myserver.com/myVirtualDir/login
myserver.com/myVirtualDir/overview
myserver.com/myVirtualDir/insights
```

After releasing the build version I have put the contents of dist folder in virtual directory named `myVirtualDir`. I have a web.config file inside the `myVirtualDir`.

I have added following rewrite rule so that I can directly open the login\overview\insights pages using the URLs mentioned above:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/myVirtualDir/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

While those rules work as expected ie., I can open the login\overview\insights pages directly, using the URLs mentioned above, it also is affecting the web api call that the application makes to fetch the data.

The api has the following format:

```
http://myserver.com/myVirtualDir/myAPI/api/categories
http://myserver.com/myVirtualDir/myAPI/api/contacts
http://myserver.com/myVirtualDir/myAPI/api/lists
and so on...
```

When api call is made, those rules are rewriting the above api URLs too. My question is how can I restrict the rules to avoid api rewriting while respecting the existing angular URL rewriting.

This is what I currently have in my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, responseType, X-Email, X-Key" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

    <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/myVirtualDir/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hello... kindly let me know if anybody has any suggestions for this.

Comment: `<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/myAPI" negate="true" />`